Both SSDs are very slow
I have two SSD on my notebook as shown here.
My first SSD (ADATA SX8200PNP (42AATCTE)) is formatted with ext4 and ntfs and mounted with the options errors=remount-ro
The result from running hdparm is:
sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/nvme0n1

/dev/nvme0n1:
 Timing cached reads:   35750 MB in  2.00 seconds = 17900.57 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 6712 MB in  3.00 seconds = 2236.95 MB/sec

My second SSD (BC901 NVMe SK hynix 1024GB (51006151)) formatted with exFAT (version 1.0) and mounted with the options users,exec,rw,suid,dev,atime,diratime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000 is running very slow.
The result from running hdparm is:
$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/nvme1n1

/dev/nvme1n1:
 Timing cached reads:   35186 MB in  2.00 seconds = 17617.49 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 6526 MB in  3.00 seconds = 2174.62 MB/sec

In both cases, compiling a small LaTeX document took minutes to complete!
Any ideas how to test/fix this issue?

That doesn't look very slow to me.

What makes you think that IO speed is the bottleneck?

Normally exFAT not recommended. The standard exFAT implementation is not journaled and only uses a single file allocation table and free space map.  Better to use NTFS if you have to share with Windows. Normally with SSD/NVMe drives you would use noatime. Do not know about atime & diratime or if they conflict. NTFS example: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420861&p=13865822#post13865822

@MechMK1 When compiling a small LaTeX file, you can see the text scrolling in slow motion.

@mikewhatever I think the same, but in practice, simple task with files took more time than in other systems, even with HDD.

@oldfred I used NTSF before, but had several problems with ownership with Windows: a folder created on Ubuntu had not write access in Windows.

That is a Windows issue. I think recently I only used Windows to create NTFS formatted partitions. But you have to make sure Windows fast startup/hibernation is off.

I just changed the mount options to defaults,nofail, and now everything is working as should be.
